# Unable to set the colour for gxt-TextField in IE

Tags: textfield, gxt

I'm not able to set the background color for the textfield in GXT. I have used

```
textfield.setStyleName("backgroung-color:red;")
textfield.setStylePrimaryName("backgroung-color:red;")
```

But it is not working in IE. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The function "setStyleName()" is not working as you expect, it sets the component class name. You can create a style class with name for example 'field-bgColor' in your css file like:

```
.field-bgColor {
    background-color: red;
}
```

after that, you would use it like following:

```
textfield.setStyleName("field-bgColor");
```

Or you can use "setStyleAttribute()" function like:

```
textfield.setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Hope it works for you :)